# Flutter TextField align text at the top

Tags: flutter, alignment, textfield

I have a TextField like this:

[image]

I want the hint and the text to be aligned at the top, not in the center.

I tried `textAlign: TextAlign.start` but that is just for the horizontal alignment.

```
TextField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
  expands: true,
  maxLines: null,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
      ),
      hintText: 'Enter Unicode text'),
),
```

How to I make the text go to the top?

*I found the answer so I am adding this as a self-answer Q&A.*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To align the text inside of a TextField to the top, use

```
textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top
```

This will give you what you want:

[image]

```
TextField(
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
  expands: true,
  maxLines: null,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
      ),
      hintText: 'Enter Unicode text'),
)
```

Answer (score 20):

Add **alignLabelWithHint: true,**

```dart
TextFormField(
  maxLines: 10,
  minLines: 5,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
      ),
      hintText: 'Enter Unicode text'),
      alignLabelWithHint: true,
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The vertical alignment of the text within an input box will be used.

> A single y value that can range from -1.0 to 1.0. -1.0 aligns to the
>   top of an input box so that the top of the first line of text fits
>   within the box and its padding. 0.0 aligns to the center of the box.
>   1.0 aligns so that the bottom of the last line of text aligns with the bottom interior edge of the input box.

You need to assure that:

> TextField.textAlignVertical, which is passed on to the InputDecorator.

```
TextField(
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
  expands: true,
  maxLines: null,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
      ),
      hintText: 'Enter Unicode text'),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```dart
TextFormField( 
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    alignLabelWithHint: true,
    label: Text('Your label name'),
  ),
)
```

Comment: please add explanation of the solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can now pass `alignLabelWithHint: true` to `InputDecoration` to cause the label to align to the top.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).